# How to check if characters exist that will be converted to "?" with GetBytes(string)

Tags: .net, unicode, character-encoding, ssis

I am writing a piece of code for a SSIS 2005 script component to read data from an informix database (where the database strings are stored as UTF8).

The output of this string needs to be loaded to a text stream (DT_TEXT), encoded using code page 1252 (ANSI - Latin I).

Here's a simple example of what I am trying to accomplish (AllColumnsBuffer is the script component output buffer, ColumnText is the name of the DT_TEXT field I am loading).

```
        Dim s As String = "Testing,1,2,3" & System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape("\u4EB5")
        AllColumnsBuffer.AddRow()
        AllColumnsBuffer.ColumnText.AddBlobData(encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(s))
```

I need to throw an error if the encoding finds characters that cannot be converted to 1252. It seems that now it just puts in a ? if a character in the source doesn't exist. Is there any way to validate that the character exists in the target code page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new encoding and then set the [`EncoderFallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.encoderfallback.aspx) property - either to your own fallback, or if an exception is good enough for you then you can use [`EncoderExceptionFallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoderexceptionfallback.aspx). Your own fallback might (say) fail gracefully without an exception, but set a flag to tell you afterwards that it failed.

Comment: Thank you! I created an instance of the encoding, setting the fallback property, and it worked! `Dim E As Encoding = encoding.GetEncoding(1252, New EncoderExceptionFallback(), New DecoderExceptionFallback())`